# Object doesn't support this property or method - jqGrid 4.4.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I'm using jqGrid 4.4.0 in an mvc2 application. The grid loads with the data fine. However, when I edit/add or delete records I get an `'Object doesn't support this property or method'` error. This is how my setup looks like on the site.master page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.16/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../Content/ui.jqgrid.css" />    
<script src="<s:url value= http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.7.min.js" type="text/jscript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you have any more details? Where is the error thrown? Do you have a stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

okay, even i got this error many times...i worked it out with two solution...first try this one, if it doesn't work for you...then paste your exact code here, where u r getting that error.

you need to include this grid.inlinedit.js if you are doing inline edit and grid.formedit.js if you are doing form edit...let me know if this sloves your problem or not...if it doesn't i'll provide the second solution

Comment: Hi Piyush, i was away for a while,  the dowload i have does not include the files you are reffering to... im doing form Edit. Where can i download these files to see if it works or not?

Comment: when u will download jqgrid plugin, these files also get downloaded with plugin, you just need to include them in your code.

Comment: and if you can let me know, where exactly you get this error?

Comment: Ok i have found the problem in the Site.Master page i had; <script src="<s:url value= http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.7.min.js" type="text/jscript"></script> instead of -  <script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.7.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>. Thanks for your help.